# Get Maximum Value

Tags: database, ms-access

I am using MS Access database. I have a table (Proposal) with the following properties:
ProposalID - PK, Title, RequestedAmount, ResearcherID - FK

I want to run an SQL query to get the candidate that has requested for the highest amount.
My query that didn't work is:

```
Select ProposalID, Title, Max(RequestedAmount) AS Budget, ResearcherID
From
Proposal;
```

How can I fix this.. Thanks

Comment: @ Abdullah Shoaib - It returns this error.. "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ProposalID' as part of an aggregate function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ProposalID, Title, RequestedAmount AS Bugdet, ResearcherID
From Proposal
WHERE RequestedAmount = (SELECT MAX(RequestedAmount) FROM Proposal);
```

You can try this One...

Comment: @ Ravi Pal - It worked but you missed RequestedAmount in the query: see my edit of your answer: Select ProposalID, Title, RequestedAmount, ResearcherID
From Proposal
WHERE RequestedAmount = (SELECT MAX(RequestedAmount) FROM Proposal);

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one

```
SELECT TOP 1 Proposal.ProposalID, Proposal.Title, (Select MAX(Proposal.RequestedAmount) from Proposal) AS Budget, Proposal.ResearcherID FROM Proposal;
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: @ Nithin - It works but unfortunately we have not been taught the Select Top clause at Uni, so I am not able to use it.. Any alternative SQL syntax to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
 Select ProposalID, Title, Max(RequestedAmount) AS Budget, ResearcherID
 From
 Proposal GROUP BY proposalID;
```

This is because you have listed multiple columns in your SQL SELECT statement that are not encapsulated in the MAX function this is why you must use the SQL GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @ Abdullah Shoaib-  It returned all the values in the table instead of the maximum RequestedAmount and other corresponding fields (ProposalID, Title,.etc)

Answer (score 0):

In an aggregate function using queries, all selected values must either be

1) in the group by

2) an aggregate function.

This is because max is not the only aggregate function - imagine if you used AVG instead of MAX. What values would SQL have to give for the other rows, that apply only to one row? There's no way to pick, which is why you cannot express such a query.

But what you want is not to aggregate but to FIND the row with the highest RequestedAmount. So let's do:

```
Select ProposalID, Title, RequestedAmount AS Budget, ResearcherID
From
Proposal
Where Budget >= ALL (select RequestedAmount from Proposal)
```